# Modify Drupal Views pagination to restrict shown page numbers

Tags: php, drupal

I have an image gallery within a Drupal site that uses the 'Image Gallery' module (funnily enough...). There is a standard 'Views' pagination system that breaks down the gallery pages into manageable chunks, and which at the same time restricts the number of page links shown (indicated by ellipses), e.g.:

```
<<first <previous ... 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... next> last>>
```

So at the moment there are always nine page links shown. **Basically I want to find out how to modify this so there are (for example) only five links shown**:

```
<<first <previous ... 6 7 8 9 10 ... next> last>>
```

I'm guessing there is some bit of PHP in the module's code that manages this, but I'm loathe to go fiddling about without knowing what I'm doing!

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy with hacking core and making this a global change to your site the quickest way is to modify includes/pager.inc and change the default value of $quantity to be the number you want.

There is a proper way to do this as well using your own theme function, if I get a chance I'll post a how to for that too.

Comment: Grand. I'd be interested to know about the other way to do it, but this is fine for now!

Comment: "hacking core?" Kitten killer! :) Seriously, there are VERY VERY few (if any, none come to mind right now) issues where you'd need to modify core files... oh yeah, there's one (updating to next version - rofl).  However, overloading them as @antoyo stated, was well done - I included a link to some other examples below as well (but puttin link here too - for you ADHD'rs who don't wanna scroll down - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6).

Answer (score 6):

you just have to overload theme_pager() in your theme, like this :

```
function your_module_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {
    return theme_pager($tags, $limit, $element, $parameters, 5);
}
```

Comment: Some good examples (more elaborate) are here... http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6.  Well done - clean and simple :) I like how you just overloaded it versus copying the entire function! Well done @antoyo.

Answer (score 2):

(Drupal 7) To do this without hacking core, copy the theme_pager function from pager.inc. Put it in your template.php file, replacing "theme" with your theme name, so the function name becomes exampleThemeName_pager, for example. Then set the $quantity variable equal to the number of pages you would like displayed.